# restart nginx after modifying settings.py and urls.py

Tags: nginx, django

In my django project, I modified the files settings.py and urls.py. My web application runs on nginx server. I reloaded the server using the following command:

/etc/init.d/nginx reload

But the changes I made in the above files don't reflect on the application. How to make this happen?

Comment: You have to restart your django app not the webserver.

Comment: @deagh As I am quite new to django, it would be really helpful if you could tell me how to restart a django app.

Comment: It depends to your way to start your app (init script or from shell or...). Tell us how you start your app.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old Question but it was #1 in the google search.

This is what solved my issue:

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```